# Is the homepage required for Schema.org breadcrumbs?

Tags: google-search, schema.org, breadcrumbs

I'm using the Schema.org markup for the breadcrumbs on the website I'm working on.

I included the homepage at first, but noticed Google is showing `site.com/ > Home > Pagetitle`. That's why I excluded the homepage and added a `WebSite` type so Google should go with `Site > Pagetitle` instead. Though, it's not updating (just yet).

I don't have any breadcrumb on the homepage (at least not in Microdata, since I removed the home from it).

Is it recommended to include the homepage breadcrumb or to exclude it?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/breadcrumbs) is the document about the breadcrumb. In this example is the homepage not included.
But i am still include the homepage so my vistor can reach the startsite. I use the startsite as position 1 and it works well. The breadcrumb will displayed incl. homepage in the serps.
And by the way if you add [This](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/site-name) the serps shows `Name > Site`an not longer `www.domain.com > Site`